# I was warned of an incoming shutdown while watching a video on Debian 11, at what settings should I look at to disable this automated feature?

Tags: debian, gnome

I updated my computer from Debian 10 to 11 this week end.

Few minutes ago, after I've started watching a video on *Firefox*, on GNOME, it warned me that my computer was about to shutdown in 60 seconds.

It's a tower PC, connected to a power source, not a laptop.

Where should I look on Debian 11 for some settings I can disable to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Do you want to disable the message or the action?

Comment: @roaima that warning and action shouldn't have happened, as I was only watching my video for few minutes. I wonder if I didn't encountered a bug. It's strange.

Comment: possible overheating ?